# Update a KivyMD button on the fly (Python)

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I have a KivyMD button that turns on (initializes) YOLO. When YOLO is initialized, the button turns green. That works, but YOLO initialization takes around 8 seconds. So I’d like to turn the button amber during initialization, and green when done. Trouble is, amber never shows, because the routine is blocking. Any ideas how I can redraw the button to show the amber color until the call to yolo_init() returns? Thank you!

```
def btn_yolo(self):
    if self.root.ids['_btn_yolo'].text_color == green: #we want to turn-off YOLO
        self.yolo.close_session()
        self.root.ids['_btn_yolo'].text_color = black #this shows
    else: #we want to initialize YOLO
        self.root.ids['_btn_yolo'].text_color = amber  #this never shows
        #update/refresh the button how?
        self.yolo = init_yolo(FLAGS) #this takes long
        self.root.ids['_btn_yolo'].text_color = green #this shows
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do your `init_yolo()` in another thread, so that it does not it does not block the color change to amber. Then that thread can call `Clock.schedule_once()` to set the color to green. This assumes that the `init_yolo()` does not make any changes to the GUI (which must be done on the main thread). This code has not been tested, so there may be some errors, but it should give you the general idea of how to do this.

```
def btn_yolo(self):
    if self.root.ids['_btn_yolo'].text_color == green: #we want to turn-off YOLO
        self.yolo.close_session()
        self.root.ids['_btn_yolo'].text_color = black #this shows
    else: #we want to initialize YOLO
        self.root.ids['_btn_yolo'].text_color = amber  #this never shows
        #update/refresh the button how?
        threading.Thread(target=self.do_init, args=(FLAGS)).start()

def do_init(self, FLAGS):
    self.yolo = init_yolo(FLAGS) #this takes long
    Clock.schedule_once(self.update_text_color)

def update_text_color(self, dt):
    self.root.ids['_btn_yolo'].text_color = green #this shows
```

Comment: Yeah, something like that would work, thank you. I was hoping for something simpler, but can't have it all. init_yolo does not affect the GUI at all, it simply  initializes the YOLO object for later use. Three stars given, but they don't show, I'm a noob around here

Comment: Been looking for a way to do that, @John Anderson, but there seems to be no check mark for noobs like me. Sorry.